# Get nvprof default behavior with ncu (NsightComputeCli)

Tags: cuda

The default `nvprof` output is great, but `nvprof` has been deprecated in favor of `ncu`. How can I make `ncu` give me an output that looks more like `nvprof`?

**minimal working example**

I have 2 `range` functions where one is called in a very unoptimal way (using only 1 thread). It takes a much longer time than the other `range` function.

**profile.cu**

```
#include <stdio.h>

//! makes sure both range functions executed correctly
bool check_range(int N, float *x_d) {
    float *x_h;
    cudaMallocHost(&x_h,N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(x_h, x_d, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    bool success=true;
    for( int i=0; i < N; i++)
        if( x_h[i] != i ) {
            printf("\33[31mERROR: x[%d]=%g\33[0m\n",i,x_h[i]);
            success=false;
            break;
        }
    cudaFreeHost(x_h);
    return success;
}

//! called with many threads
__global__ void range_fast(int N, float *x) {
    for( int i=threadIdx.x; i < N; i+=blockDim.x)
        x[i]=i;
}

//! only gets called with 1 thread. This is the bottleneck I want to detect
__global__ void range_slow(int N, float *x) {
    for( int i=threadIdx.x; i < N; i+=blockDim.x)
        x[i]=i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int N=(1<<20)*10;
    float *x_fast, *x_slow;
    cudaMalloc(&x_fast,N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&x_slow,N*sizeof(float));
    range_fast<<<1,512>>>(N,x_fast);
    range_slow<<<1,1>>>(N,x_slow);
    check_range(N,x_fast);
    check_range(N,x_slow);
    cudaFree(x_fast);
    cudaFree(x_slow);
    return 0;
};
```

**compilation**

```sh
nvcc profile.cu -o profile.exe
```

**`nvprof` profiling**

```sh
nvprof ./profile.exe
```

**`nvprof` output**

```
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   99.17%  1.20266s         1  1.20266s  1.20266s  1.20266s  range_slow(int, float*)
                    0.53%  6.3921ms         2  3.1961ms  3.1860ms  3.2061ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
                    0.31%  3.7273ms         1  3.7273ms  3.7273ms  3.7273ms  range_fast(int, float*)
      API calls:   88.79%  1.20524s         2  602.62ms  3.2087ms  1.20203s  cudaMemcpy
                    9.31%  126.39ms         2  63.196ms  100.62us  126.29ms  cudaMalloc
                    1.11%  15.121ms         2  7.5607ms  7.5460ms  7.5754ms  cudaHostAlloc
                    0.64%  8.6687ms         2  4.3344ms  4.2029ms  4.4658ms  cudaFreeHost
                    0.09%  1.2195ms         2  609.73us  103.80us  1.1157ms  cudaFree
```

This gives me a clear idea about which functions are taking most of the runtime, and that `range_slow` is the bottleneck.

**`ncu` profiling**

```sh
ncu ./profile.exe
```

**`ncu` output**

The `ncu` output has far more details, most of which I don't really care about. It also isn't as nicely summarized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality of `nvprof` has been broken into [2 separate tools](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/migrating-nvidia-nsight-tools-nvvp-nvprof/) in the "new" profiling tools.    The Nsight Compute tool is mostly focused on the activity of kernel (i.e. device code) profiling, and although it can report kernel duration, of course, it is less interested in things like API call activity and memory copy activity.

The tool that has this functionality is Nsight Systems.

Try:

```
nsys profile --stats=true ./profile.exe
```

Amongst other things, you will get a pareto list of GPU activities (broken into separate pareto lists of kernel activities and memory copy activities) and a pareto list of API calls.

In newer versions of nsight systems, a new capability has been added. Certain `nvprof` command options (not all) can be issued via `nsys`. Try:

```
nsys nvprof --print-gpu-trace ./profile.exe
```

This gives a close analog to the `nvprof --print-gpu-trace` tool for example.

Comment: It looks like a new and improved version of `nvprof` that shows both host OS and device side information. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!